# Way to alter behavior based on caller using property getter without reflection or making caller a member in Python

Tags: python, reflection, frameworks

So I'm writing a test framework for a large website, and am currently working on modeling the UI driver.  I have a UI Session that abstracts a number of emulators and drivers for browsers and mobile devices.  this object also holds state information about the browser session, including a history of page objects, the top of which is the current page.  My problem is that I want my page objects to lazy load data from the browser (properties set up with getters that check whether we've extracted the data, if not, whether this is the current page, and if so, pulls the data from the browser and caches it in the page object), but that means they need access to the abstraction layer provided by the session.

The first idea of course was just sticking the session in the page, but that creates a circular reference, which is bad.  I also considered trying to define multiple interfaces for page, but I couldn't see how that would really work too well.  What I really want is to be able to intercept the call in session then have session redirect the call down to page to a hidden getter that also takes session as an argument, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do that.

Is there a good solution or design pattern that I could use here to get the info and access I need where I need it without having circular references or giving up lazy loading?  I don't want to make the interface more complicated by forcing users to sometimes call methods and sometimes call properties or members to access the same info (the idea is to hide the fancy footwork behind the scenes and make using the framework dead simple).

I actually do have a CurrentPage class that all it does is store the current_page in a class variable which is set by session on navigate events, so I suppose I could make current_page a magic global-esque accessor that would be the only way to actually get data off the page and have it use a special interface and store the session object as well, but that seems clunky to me.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you writing your own framework? Is there a reason selenium or something similar didn't meet your needs?

Comment: @Daenyth It's on top of selenium, to implement domain specific logic.  As I said, it also abstracts multiple emulators and browser drivers so we can do mobile testing with the same framework.  Of course that is entirely beside the point...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

"The first idea of course was just sticking the session in the page, but that creates a circular reference, which is bad."

But that's not true.  Circular references won't get garbage collected instantly the way non-circular ones will, and `__del__` methods won't get called, but as long as you're aware of both of those limitations and don't have needs that conflict with them, circular references are fine.  See:

[`http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__)

Having pages store a reference to the session should be fine.

Edit: if session and page are in different files and circular imports become an issue, you can use an approach like this:

```
# session.py
import page
class Session(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.page_list = []
    def addPage(self, url):
        self.page_list.append(page.Page(self, url))

# page.py
class Page(object):
    def __init__(self, session, url):
        self.session = session
        self.url = url
```

As long as you don't need to *construct* Sessions inside of page.py you won't need to import it at all, since there won't be a need for capital-S Session (the class).  If that changes, you can do something like:

```
# page.py
class Page(object):
    # ...
    def something(self):
        import session
        self.other_session = session.Session()
```

Comment: I guess I'll just go with this.  I don't really like it, but it will work quick and dirty...

Comment: It's unclear why you're reluctant to use circular references.  Are there additional restrictions or constraints to your problem that you haven't covered in detail?

Comment: My past experience has been that over time, as code is maintained and features are added, circular references turn in to circular imports, and circular imports cause circular headaches.